# substring in JS not working

Tags: javascript, ejs

here is the situation: I want to limit the numbers of signs in my index page with receips.

The full paragraph is:

```
 <p>  <%= recipe.elaboration %> </p>
```

It works just perfect. I add the substring() method:

```
<p>  <%- recipe.elaboration.substring(0, 100) %> </p>
```

And i got this as a result:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/RecipeApp/views/index.ejs:18
 >> 18|   <p>  <%- recipe.elaboration.substring(0,3) %> </p>
```

Anyone?

Comment: you should put recipe.elaboration = recipe.elaboration.substring(0, 100) in JS before you call template render

Comment: why have you changed it to <%- ?

Comment: Luca: <%= escapes the HTML going into the buffer, while <%- does not.